# How do i find number of Cycles of a processor?

Tags: cpu-architecture, processor

I am kind of confused on how to find the number of cycles. Although it appears to be pretty simple.

Is it supposed to be number of cycles = (Clock Rate) * (CPI) * (Time)

or

number of cycles = (Clock Rate) * (Time)

[image shows required information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsBTk.png)

This is the question:
**If the processors each execute a program in 100 seconds, find the number of cycles and the number of instructions for each processor**

i saw 2 solutions which made me confused, that's why i need your help

Comment: The clock-rate **is** the number-of-cycles (per-second).

Comment: #cycles = time period * clock rate. #instructions = cycles / (cycles per instruction). Most CPUs don't work like this since pipelining was introduced around 30 years ago.

Comment: Hey thank you. Pretty sure tats the formula.